# Amazon Cognito user pool v/s federated identity providers

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm creating an application using JS in which I have to use amazon Cognito for Signup and login. As my basic understanding we are using user pool to create our data dictionary, but if we want to login with social media we use Identity Providers.

As my requirement I have to use both, How I have to Implement this?
I have to create two apps in cognito or I can add in user pool ??

please share a code snippet if exist

Comment: This is a very broad question. Can you clarify a little or be more specific? Cognito User pools functions as sort of your user directory that you can use to provide authentication in your web or mobile app. In user pools you can federate uesrs with different social providers such as Facebook or Google so that is possible as well. Code snippets for the first can be found at https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js and you would have to use the Auth SDK to federate with social providers https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js

Comment: I had added Identity provider (facebook) in user pool also setup the URI in facebook app, 
After that when I have to call the Credentials.get method it requires IdentityPoolId for that I had created a new federated pool and add the user pool detail there to achieve the IdentityPoolId. 

when I'm calling the function get and have not added any Identity provider in federated pool it returns me error, but If I added it on federated pool it returns seesion token and all. And user is adding into federated table wheather I setup the mapping in user  pool.

Comment: If we have to add federated pool then why we are adding identitity provider in user pool??

when I had set the mapping in user pool than why my faderated data is not visible in user pool facebook group?

Answer (score 0):

You can [sign-in through a third-party provider using only User Pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-identity-federation.html). As a rule of thumb, use User Pools when you want to authorize something via JWT and Federated Identities when you want to access AWS services directly (more info [here](https://hackernoon.com/aws-cognito-user-pools-or-identity-pools-what-do-i-use-to-secure-my-api-1d69cfbe99e1))